# Prevent Outlook for Mac from selecting the entire word when selecting text?

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, text

How do I prevent Outlook for Mac (*currently v16... but earlier versions too*) from selecting the entire word when selecting text?

This seems to be default Microsoft Office behavior. Word for Mac has a setting in its preferences that you can disable* but Outlook does not. This is from Word's preferences:

[image: godsend]

Related: I discovered that if you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while you select text, Outlook will use the typical text selection method (*start selecting text at my cursor position, end selecting text at my cursor position*). This is useful, but I'd like the <kbd>Alt</kbd> method to be the default... which is inline with every other Non-Microsoft Office application that I have ever encountered on the Mac.

---

**I seem to remember at some point in Office for Mac, that making this change in Word would affect other Office apps too. I could very well be misremembering though.*

Comment: What do you meany by "when selecting text"? Exactly how do you select text?

Comment: @Alper Using the mouse. Let me see if I can add an animated gif.